# Convergence of stochastic process sample path to deterministic function

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a sequence of stochastic processes $\{X_{n,t}; t\geq 0\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\mathsf E(X_{n,t})=f_n(t)=ng(t)$ where $n$ is some parameter and $g$ is just a function of $t$ (i.e. no dependence on $n$ for $g$). Furthermore assume that $\mathsf{Var}(X_{n,t}/n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$ So we have that, for each fixed $t$, $X_{n,t}/n$ converges to $g(t)$ in probability as $n\rightarrow\infty.$ If it helps, we can also assume that there is a bound $|X_{n,t}|<M$ surely for all $n$ and $t.$

**Question:** Can we in any sense justify saying that: 
$$``X_{n,t} \text{ converges to } f_n(t)"$$
even if $X_{n,t}$ and $f_n(t)$ grow unboundedly for fixed $t$ values?

Maybe 
$$d(X_{n,t},f_n(t))=\frac{\sup_{t\geq0}|X_{n,t}-f_n(t)|}{n}$$ 
or 
$$d(X_{n,t},f_n(t))=\int_0^\infty \frac{(X_{n,t}-f_n(t))^2}{n^2} \ dt$$ 
or something else can serve as a metric so that $d(X_{n,t},f_n(t))$ converges to zero in probability? Is this idea of mixing metrics and probabilistic convergence a bit absurd?

The idea is that the graphs of $X_{n,t}$ and $f_n(t)$ as functions of $t$ are quite distinct for small $n$ and are visibly indistinguishable for large $n$, even though the maximal extent of the range of both graphs grows unboundedly in $n$.

The motivating example is radioactive decay, where $n$ is the initial number of particles that decay at rate $\alpha$. Let $X_{n,t}$ represent this stochastic process (for fixed $n$ and $t$, $X_{n,t}$ is just a binomial for $n$ trials and probability of success $e^{-\alpha t}$). In some sense, for a large number of initial particles $X_{n,t}$ is 'close' to $ne^{-\alpha t}.$ Is there an appropriate way to define this 'closeness' or is scaling by $n$ the only reasonable way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of convergence in distribution of random functions is standard.  The classical example is [Donsker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) which  probably does not contain the exact solution to your problem but does give a taste of the kind of thing involved.  There are two interlocking key steps.  You have to pick a function space for your random elements live in, and you have to check a condition called "tightness", which involves (loosely speaking) a probabilistic bound on how wiggly the random functions can be. The details are technical, and vary from problem to problem. A classical (and readable) book on the subject is Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*.

That being said, your notions about scaling are naive.  You seem to be  looking for a result of form "$a_n$ converges to $b_n$" when you really want a result of form "$a_n/f(n)$ has such-and-such a limit", or "$(a_n-b_n)/g(n)$ has such-and-such a limit".

Comment: Yes, I know it seems naive... The graphs are just so convincing. So dividing by $n$, we can talk about convergence of the sequence of random functions $X_{n,t}/n$ to $g(t)$ as long as we set up the function space appropriately?

Comment: Yes.  In your case, you might consider the empirical distribution function of $n$ iid exponential random variables (each representing the lifetime of one particular particle), which I think might actually be 1 minus your $f_n(t)/n$, and use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem to show that your $f_n(t)/n$ converges uniformly to your $g(t)$.

Comment: I think that theorem matches what I'm trying to go for. Thanks!